# Checking a key exists or not in a dictionary

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this

```
odict([(1, {'media_one': '000121'}), (2, {'media_two': '201984'}), (3, {'media_three': '301984'})])
```

I want to check if the key media_two or media_one or media_three is exists in this dictionary or not. If exists do something else do nothing.
How can we check

Comment: odict is an ordered dict. I have created like this   from odict import odict as OrderedDict  media_dict = OrderedDict(). then media_dict.update({
                    1:{'media_one':'000121'},
                    2:{'media_two':'201984'},
                    3:{'media_three':'301984'},
                })

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> odict = OrderedDict([(1, {'media_one': '000121'}), (2, {'media_two': '201984'}), (3, {'media_three': '301984'})])
>>> any("media_one" in item for item in odict.values())
True
```

This checks that one of the keys is present. To check for all of the keys:

```
>>> all(any(key in item for item in odict.values()) 
...                     for key in ("media_one", "media_two", "media_three"))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

`(lambda d: ["media_one" in m for m in d.values()])(odict)`

Output

`[True, False, False]`